# Issues With Adding Entity Framework to .Net Standard Class Library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-standard-2.0

I am trying to add entity framework to a .Net Standard 2.0 Class Library.

I have tried creating the classes from the DB. I ran the following Command in the nuget package manager console.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=localhost;Database=FlexDB;uid=root;pwd=ffff;Trusted_Connection=True;" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir EFModels/DB
```

It unfortunately produces the following error.

> Startup project 'FlexData' targets framework '.NETStandard'. There is
>   no runtime associated with this framework, and projects targeting it
>   cannot be executed directly. To use the Entity Framework Core Package
>   Manager Console Tools with this project, add an executable project
>   targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core that references this project,
>   and set it as the startup project; or, update this project to
>   cross-target .NET Framework or .NET Core.

UPDATE-------------

I have followed the instruction from ChrFin but I now get the following error

> Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

Blimey it was easier with an EDMX file and template!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

To run such commands you need a library targeting a runtime (Full or core framework).
Just create an additional project, e.g. a console project targeting .NET 4.5 or newer, and a reference to your .NET standard library.
After setting the new project as the startup project you can then run the command against your original project and get the DB scaffolded in there.

Comment: Will that not create the Entities in the Runtime Project?

Comment: @coolblue2000 I honestly don't know. Just try it and either move it manually  afterwards or check if there is a parameter to change that. Anyway there is no way around such a "helper-project" as the PMC needs to know which runtime to use...

Comment: The project targeting the .NET Standard project only needs to be the *startup* project. You can still scaffold in the .NET Standard project by running the command targeting that project.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. I assume this means that the .net Standard project is then no longer a "standard" project that can be used with other .net versions?

Comment: @coolblue2000 Yes, it is. You **keep** the current .NET Standard project with Entity Framework. You **add** an executable project (console, web, ...) that you set as the startup project (which also holds the connectionstring in its config). Then you run the scaffold command from the Package Manager Console targeting the .NET Standard project. That should do the trick.

Comment: @coolblue2000 No, it will just run the command with the framework/runtime  from that project but still creates a .NET standard compatible context into your original project. (@RickVanDenBosch thanks for the info!)

Comment: I have updated my initial question as I now get a new error.

Comment: @coolblue2000 Please check if all your packages are installed correctly, because I just tested this with a new solution/projects and it worked fine. Only difference: I used MS SQL, as i do not have MySQL installed...

Comment: Yep, All packages are correct and up to date. (That is all packages that I think should be there...)

Comment: @coolblue2000 Maybe try this provider: https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql This one definitely states it supports scaffolding for MySQL. Or try it with MS SQL and a demo-DB just to verify the problem is with the provider.

Comment: Just one more concern. How do I tell the command which tables I want to use with EF? And how do I specify function imports?

Comment: @coolblue2000 use the '-Tables TABLE1,TABLE2' parameter, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db#reverse-engineer-your-model

Comment: @ChrFin

Do you have VS solution, which works as explained by you here? I tried my best but somehow I'm not able to make it work.

I'm trying to make Migrations work with Xamarin.Forms project with Entity Framework Core 2.0.

Thanks,

Comment: @user2185592 I have a solution here using XF and EFC 1.1 (not 2.0 as I also target Win 10 Mobile) and it works fine (at least when the UWP project is the startup project).

Comment: @ChrFin
Possible for you to share the  VS solution code?

Comment: @user2185592 There is nothing special about my solution, so no need to share (can't do it anyhow, as it is company code). May tell us what your real problem is, and we can then help? `I'm not able to make it work` does not tell much about what your problem is...

Comment: @ChrFin

I have Xamarin.Forms application in which I want to make use of Entity Framework Core 2.0. Using the Models definition and Datacontext.EnsureCreated, I have been able to create the sqlite database with tables as per Model definition. However, Models will keep changing during the course of development. So how I can propagate the changes in the Model to database tables? DbContext.EnsureCreated is not helping to propagate Model changes. I understand that Migrations like (non core) EF should solve this problem. So can you provide steps to achieve the same?

Comment: @user2185592 There is not much difference in EF an EFC regarding migration handling. Just that EFC does not need a `Enable-Migrations` command - simply execute `Add-Migration NAME` and your good to go...